# What is the error for this MySQL function for lat-lng distance?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, coordinates, distance

I am trying to insert a function that I found on the web into my MySQL database that should calculate the distance between 2 points given their respective coordinates.
I found the function here: http://www.sqlexamples.info/SPAT/mysql_distance.htm

This is what I'm trying to insert into MySQL:

```
USE city_notifier; /*it is the name of my database*/

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_distance;

CREATE FUNCTION fn_distance 
  (p_x1 FLOAT, p_y1 FLOAT, p_x2 FLOAT, p_y2 FLOAT) 
  RETURNS FLOAT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE v_dist FLOAT;
  DECLARE A FLOAT; DECLARE B FLOAT; 
  DECLARE C FLOAT; DECLARE D FLOAT;
  /* 
   returns distance calculation between two points in
   LAT-LONG coordinates 
  */

  SET v_dist = 0; 

  -- convert to radians 
  SET A = p_x1 / 57.29577951; 
  SET B = p_y1 / 57.29577951; 
  SET C = p_x2 / 57.29577951; 
  SET D = p_y2 / 57.29577951; 

  IF (A = C && B = D) THEN 
   SET v_dist = 0; 
  ELSEIF ((sin(A)*sin(C)+cos(A)*cos(C)*cos(B - D)) > 1) THEN 
   SET v_dist = 3963.1 * acos(1); 
  ELSE 
   SET v_dist = 3963.1*acos(sin(A)*sin(C) + cos(A)*cos(C)*cos(B - D)); 
  END IF;

  SET v_dist = v_dist * 1.609;

  /* return distance in km. */ 
  RETURN v_dist;

END;
```

It continues to give me an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6.
But I cannot find any error in the function.
Can you guys help me please? What is wrong with that function?

Comment: I'm using PhpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2 with MySQL 5.5.27.

Comment: Are you trying to find distance between 2 specific points or  finding the nearest points in database to 1 specific point?

Comment: Just trying to find the distance between 2 points given their coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
USE city_notifier; /*it is the name of my database*/

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_distance;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fn_distance 
  (p_x1 FLOAT, p_y1 FLOAT, p_x2 FLOAT, p_y2 FLOAT) 
  RETURNS FLOAT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
  DECLARE v_dist FLOAT;
  DECLARE A FLOAT; DECLARE B FLOAT; 
  DECLARE C FLOAT; DECLARE D FLOAT;
  /* 
   returns distance calculation between two points in
   LAT-LONG coordinates 
  */

  SET v_dist = 0; 

  -- convert to radians 
  SET A = p_x1 / 57.29577951; 
  SET B = p_y1 / 57.29577951; 
  SET C = p_x2 / 57.29577951; 
  SET D = p_y2 / 57.29577951; 

  IF (A = C && B = D) THEN 
   SET v_dist = 0; 
  ELSEIF ((sin(A)*sin(C)+cos(A)*cos(C)*cos(B - D)) > 1) THEN 
   SET v_dist = 3963.1 * acos(1); 
  ELSE 
   SET v_dist = 3963.1*acos(sin(A)*sin(C) + cos(A)*cos(C)*cos(B - D)); 
  END IF;

  SET v_dist = v_dist * 1.609;

  /* return distance in km. */ 
  RETURN v_dist;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It worked! What does that "DELIMITER $$" do exactly?

Comment: It defines a new delimiter (here $$) instead of the default one that is ";" to separate statements that will compose your script.
Have a look here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript-delimiter.html
cheers

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try

```
  IF ((A = C) && (B = D)) THEN
```

to make it work.

Comment: It's not a logical error. The function won't even load into MySQL. It says it's a syntax error.

Comment: that's confusing. i compiled your function on my mysql 5.6 after first having the same error as you and then adding this change.